# How can I keep the same colors during daylight cycle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to develop a program to mine blocks based on color recognition, but when the color has been set during the day and it's night or vice versa the color changes just enough to not recognize it. Is there a way to keep the colors similar without changing the daylight cycle setting? (I have my brightness all the way up)

Comment: Out of the box solution: Have your program detect night, plunk down a bed, and sleep until day.

Comment: There was mods for older versions of Minecraft that allowed you to turn on "night vision", wherein all blocks was visible with maximum brightness, as though everything had their own personal super-bright light source. I think [Optifine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1272953-optifine-hd-a4-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and) did this, but there was others as well.

Comment: You could record the block colour values for all light levels.  That should solve the problem.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen and now there are night vision potions

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think I will just set a second color for night time like @MBraedley said. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Sometimes it's the simplest ideas.

Answer (score -1):

Use a redstone clock, spamming this command:

/effect minecraft:night_vision 10 1 true